# ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt install python3-pip -y]: exit code: 100 on docker

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I try to build a python web app with flask when I run docker build -t xxx/mywebapp . --pull I get this erreur :

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                              
 => => transferring dockerfile: 342B                                                                                              
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                   
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                  
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                     
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest@sha256:2adf22367284330af9f832ffefb717c78239f6251d9d0f58de50b86229ed1427
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                 
 => => transferring context: 440B                                                                                                 
 => CACHED [2/6] RUN apt update                                                                                                   
 => ERROR [3/6] RUN apt install python3-pip -y                                                                                   
------                                                                                                                                 
 > [3/6] RUN apt install python3-pip -y:   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#0 23.86 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.140474748197376'dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
#0 23.87  installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#0 23.88 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 23.88  python3.10-minimal
#0 23.94 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt install python3-pip -y]: exit code: 100
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Mettre à jour les packages 
RUN apt update
# Installer Python et pip
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install Flask


WORKDIR /

COPY . .

# Exposer le port 8000 pour l'application
EXPOSE 8000

# Démarrer l'application
CMD ["python3", "-m","flask","run","--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

python file webapp.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000)
```

The same think with apt install any python package on ubuntu image dockerfile.

Comment: `RUN dpkg --configure -a && apt install -y python3`

Comment: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dpkg --configure -a && apt install -y python3]: exit code: 100

Comment: take a look in this solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065556/broken-python-dependencies-after-trying-to-re-install)